# Long running task is blocking the UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am new to TPL and I am trying to test a very simple application using parallelism.

I am using a WinForms, C#, VS2015

In my form, I have one progress bar, a timer and a gauge. 
I am using **Infragistics 15.2** controls.

- the button will launch a function which does some work
- Form Load will start a Windows.Form.Timer and instantiate the `PerformanceCounter`
- On `timer.Tick` (I set a 500ms interval), I read the CPU usage from the PerformanceCounter and update the value of the Gauge control.

My problem is that the first access to NextValue() of the CPU counter is really time expensive and freezes the UI. 
I was expecting to have a full responsive UI but still it freezes. I am missing something for sure, but I cannot find out what.
I am pretty sure that The blocking action is the `NextValue()`: if I replace it with a random number generator, my UI is fully responsive.

Can you please help me?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PerformanceCounter _CPUCounter;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private async void ultraButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progress = new Progress<int>(valuePBar => {ultraProgressBar1.Value = valuePBar; });
        await Task.Run(() => UpdatePBar(progress));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _CPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            _CPUCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            _CPUCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            _CPUCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                timer1.Interval = 500;
                timer1.Start();
            }));
        });
    }


    private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float usage = await Task.Run(() => _CPUCounter.NextValue());
        RadialGauge r_gauge = (RadialGauge)ultraGauge1.Gauges[0];
        r_gauge.Scales[0].Markers[0].Value = usage;
    }

    public void UpdatePBar(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        for (Int32 seconds = 1; seconds <= 10; seconds++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //simulate Work, do something with the data received
            if (seconds != 10 && progress != null)
            {
                progress.Report(seconds * 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be unrelated, but you should not update the UI element (gauge in your case) from the non UI thread. For the sake of test, what happens of you comment out the gauge code, i.e. leave only `float usage = _CPUCounter.NextValue();` line inside?

Comment: What is the scope of _CPUCounter?  Is it static?

Comment: @IvanStoev the UI is freezing anyway. I simply left that line of code. BTW, What do you suggest me to update the UI? For progress bar
For button, on `Click` event, I call a method which starts a Task:
`MyMethod((valuePBar) => UpdateProgressBar(valuePBar));`
then


`private void UpdateProgressBar(Int32 valuePBar)
        {

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {               
this.progressBar.Value = valuePBar;
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, this.ui_TaskScheduler);
        }`

Comment: @ChrisBallance it is a public variable.

Comment: Whaw! Why tasks, `Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke` is the WinForms standard way to update UI from another thread. What about the UI freezing, looks like it's from another place, the posted code cannot freeze the UI. Can you post small, but full sample code that we can copy/paste and see the issue?

Comment: This article by Jon Skeet may help you out http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Comment: @IvanStoev so maybe I am doing everything wrong.. The code I posted before was for the progress bar. It is not causing the freezing. Since you told that I was updating the UI in the wrong way, I posted that piece of code to show you how I am doing stuff, and to know from you if it's wrong. I had taken that piece of code from a demo in CodeProject.

Comment: The interval you're running this at might be a bit low for the overhead of TPL here.  Try increasing your interval to say 200ms.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. I am trying to do something new and would prefer to avoid old paradigms. Do you think it is possible to do something very simple using TPL?

Comment: @Valentina I meant the code inside your original post (`OnTimerTickElapsed`) cannot freeze the UI. We need [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ChrisBallance same result with 500ms

Comment: @IvanStoev I can guarantee that it is freezing :(
I just posted my code example
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You should:

- Never update UI controls from background threads.
- Prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`.
- Prefer `async`/`await` if you want to "return to the UI thread".
- Use `IProgress<T>` for progress updates.
- Only use `TaskScheduler`s or `SynchronizationContext`s if absolutely necessary (and they're not necessary here).
- Never use `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Control.Invoke`.

In this case, your timer can just run `NextValue` on a thread pool thread using `Task.Run`, and then update the UI with the resulting value:

```
private async void OnTimerTickElapsed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  float usage = await Task.Run(() => _CPUCounter.NextValue());
  RadialGauge r_gauge = (RadialGauge)this.ultraGauge.Gauges[0];                   
  r_gauge.Scales[0].Markers[0].Value = usage;
}
```

For your progress bar, have your `MyMethod` take an `IProgress<int>`:

```
private void ButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var progress = new Progress<int>(valuePBar => { this.progressBar.Value = valuePBar; });
  MyMethod(progress);
}

MyMethod(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  ...
  progress.Report(50);
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, using `await` keyword causes compile error, maybe due to the fact that NextValue function has no `async` modifier.

Comment: I don't understand the IProgress part. MyMethod is the one calculating the value to update the progressBar.

Comment: @Valentina: `NextValue` doesn't have to be `async`. The compiler error you're seeing is probably because you forgot to make `OnTimerTickElapsed` `async`. The `IProgress<T>` is a way of *reporting* progress updates; `MyMethod` still calculates the progress update value just like it did before.

Comment: Got it. I made the `OnTimerTickElapsed async` but nothing has changed. Again, the problem has not been solved. Let's try to ignore the progress bar (thank for your suggestions, BTW). Did you succeed in having a fully responsive Ui with the `PerformanceCounter`?

Comment: @Valentina: `NextValue` cannot possibly block the UI with this code. If your UI is blocking, it's some other code that's doing it. Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I have already put all my code here. The thing is: If I replace the performancecounter with a stupid random number generator, all is working. Why couldn;t it be the performance counter?

Comment: @Valentina: It can't be `NextValue` because that method does not run on the UI thread. A "minimal, reproducible example" is the smallest amount of code that someone else can copy/paste into an application, and have it reproduce the problem. Your current code does not define `_CPUCounter` or `ultraGauge`.

Comment: I simplified the code. I put only one progress bar, one gauge and one combobox with 3 ABC fields
How can I post the code? it is too long for the admitted length of a comment. Anyway, the siomplified code still freezed, NOT ALWAYS, but sometime freezes

Comment: @Valentina: Try replacing the gauge with a textbox or something, since random Internet people are likely not going to have the same gauge control you're using. Then edit your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Three things...

1. Simplify your Thread Synchronization context for the progress bar.  Just use `Task.Run(() => { // progress bar code }`
2. Check that `CPUCounter` is not `static`
3. Make sure your `_CPUCounter.NextValue()` method supports async and is awaited, otherwise it will block.

I would also favor `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew` as it has better defaults (it calls `Task.Factory.StartNew` internally)

```
private void OnTimerTickElapsed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                float usage = await _CPUCounter.NextValue();           
                RadialGauge r_gauge = (RadialGauge)this.ultraGauge.Gauges[0];                   
                r_gauge.Scales[0].Markers[0].Value = usage;
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
```

Have a look at the interval you're using.  50ms is a tad bit fast for the overhead of TPL.

Comment: Good point.  It looks like access to _CPUCounter may be blocking if it is static

Comment: 1) not static

2) How can I verify if `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` supports async?

3) Same outcome with 500ms

Comment: With your code added for the progress bar, this is your issue, not the perf counter.  See my comment on your code.

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code (just replaced the gauge with a simple label showing the `usage` variable and of course didn't click the button because you didn't provide `MyMethod`) and didn't experience any UI blocking.

Posting the correct code for updating the UI (using `Task` for that purpose even with UI scheduler IMO is a overkill):

```
private void UpdateProgressBar(Int32 valuePBar)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        this.progressBar.Value = valuePBar;
    }));
}

private void OnTimerTickElapsed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        float usage = _CPUCounter.NextValue();
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            RadialGauge r_gauge = (RadialGauge)this.ultraGauge.Gauges[0];
            r_gauge.Scales[0].Markers[0].Value = usage;
        }));
    });
}
```

Still, there is no visible reason in your code that can cause UI blocking.
Except eventually this part

```
_CPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
_CPUCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
_CPUCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
_CPUCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
```

which runs on the UI thread in your `OnFormLoad`. You can try moving that code on a separate task like this

```
private void OnFormLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        _CPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        _CPUCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        _CPUCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        _CPUCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.timer.Interval = 500;
            this.timer.Start();
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot MyMethod

` public static void MyMethod(Action<Int32> CallBack)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                    CallBack(20);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                    CallBack(40);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    updateUICallBack(60);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    CallBack(80);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                   CallBack(100);
                });
        }`

Comment: Please try to add myMethod to your code. I am still experiencing the freezing. I am pretty sure that the gauge is causing the problem. If I don't start the timer, everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

[Somebody has already investigated this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297649/performancecounter-creation-take-a-long-time)

The problem is that PerformanceCounter initialization is complex and takes a lot of time. What is not clear though is that whether this initialization block all threads or just the owning thread(the thread that creates the PerformanceCounter).

But I think your code already provided the answer. Since you are already creating the PerformanceCounter in a thread pool thread and it still blocks the UI. Then it is probably correct to assume the initialization blocks all threads.

If the initialization blocks all threads, then the solution would be to initialize the PerformanceCounter on application startup. Either by not using the default constructor(pick a constructor that not only constructs the instance but also initializes it) or call NextValue once during startup.

Comment: I ran into the same issue today. It seems only the current thread is blocked: wrapping the initialization of the performance counter inside a Task.Run() solves the problem.